# Is my Touch Screen Digitalizer supported?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, touch-screen, multi-touch

I am hoping that the "10-point capacitive multi-touch"-digitalizer of an [11" convertible notebook](https://www.trekstor.de/products/2in1/detail-2in1/product/primebook-C11B.html) is supported by the Linux kernel, but I have a feeling that it probably isn't... how can I determine this?

from the command line:

```
$ uname -a  
Linux fedora0 5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 5 21:28:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo udevadm info --export-db | grep "ID_INPUT_TOUCH"  
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHPAD=1  
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHPAD=1  
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHPAD=1
```

```
$ xinput --list  
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.   
⎡ Virtual core pointer              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16           id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16  id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard             id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ xinput_calibrator   
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "xwayland-pointer:16"  
current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=65535 and min_y=0, max_y=65535    
If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL)
```

```
$ sudo find / -name "*touchscreen*"  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.7-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.7-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.ko.xz  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.ko.xz  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen  
/usr/lib/modules/5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.ko.xz  
/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/as/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/ca/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/cs/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/da/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/de/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/el/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/es/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page   
/usr/share/help/fi/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/fr/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/gl/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/gu/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/he/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/hi/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/hr/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/hu/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/id/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/it/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/ja/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/kn/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/lv/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/mr/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/nl/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/pa/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/pl/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/pt/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/pt_BR/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/ro/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/ru/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/sl/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/sr/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/sr@latin/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/sv/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/ta/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/te/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/vi/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page  
/usr/share/help/zh_CN/gnome-help/touchscreen-gestures.page
```

```
$ xrandr   
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767  
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 260mm x 150mm
```

Comment: @muru: is this satisfactory? please help if I missed something of the guidelines

Comment: Yes, that's much better, thanks!